# How do I automate the installation of acroread?

Tags: preseed, adobe-acrobat

I would like to install acroread via script without interaction. Is there a way to pre-accept the license agreement?

Answer (score 0):

Using [expect](http://www.nist.gov/el/msid/expect.cfm) is good and easy way of doing so. People use Expect to automate interaction with non-GUI (and typically non-cursor-controlled) applications that prompt the user for input.